# vs 2017 could not connect to Team Foundation Service server

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I recently installed vs 2017 enterprise on my local win-10 computer. But when I try to connect to my remote tfs server through Team Explorer, It pop out a error message which said that " An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permission xxxxxxxxx", here "xxxx" is my remote server IP address. I think there must be some settings on my computer or VS settings that cause the problem, as I can connect to the servier through VS 2012. Is there any one who could help me solving this? Much thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of tfs do you use ?

Comment: The tfs server version is 2015, I also find that nether can my VS 10 connect to the server. Great thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi@JiangMike any update on this?Have you figured it out?

Comment: Yes , thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to the error info, it sounds like your connections for VS 2017 are being interrupted by your network. Are you behind a proxy or do you have some network security software running?

Suggest you move the proxy and temporarily disable your anti virus software. Then try to connect TFS and use VS2017 again.

In many cases when folks see this sort of behavior it's because they had network security exemptions for VS 2015 and none for 2017; please double check if that's the case

> Our authentication scheme has also changed for 2017 from 2015 where
>   the latter used credential cookies and the former is now using bearer
>   authentication tokens. The two have different headers and we've seen
>   some proxy software strip the bearer tokens from outgoing packets
>   where it didn't do so for the 2015-and-before token headers.

Besides, also update your [vs 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) enterprise to latest version.